# Problem with <script src="{{asset('js/app.js') }}"defer></script>. If I delete this line, no other script works

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a problem with this script: <script src="{{asset('js/app.js') }}"defer>
I use Laravel. An this script is in: footer.blade.php:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="src/js/vendor/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="{{asset('template/plugins/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('template/plugins/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('template/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/dist/perfect-scrollbar.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('template/plugins/screenfull/dist/screenfull.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('template/plugins/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('template/plugins/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('template/plugins/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('template/plugins/datatables.net-responsive-bs4/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('template/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('template/plugins/jvectormap/tests/assets/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('template/plugins/moment/moment.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('template/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/build/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('template/plugins/d3/dist/d3.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('template/plugins/c3/c3.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('template/js/tables.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('template/js/widgets.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('template/js/charts.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('template/dist/js/theme.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/app.js') }}"defer></script>
        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#datepicker").datetimepicker({
                    format: 'Y-m-d'
                })
            })
        </script>
```

This footer.blade.php is including in all php files in the projects. If I don't delete this line with script defer, this line doesn't work anymore:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#datepicker").datetimepicker({
                    format: 'Y-m-d'
                })
            })
        </script>
```

And if I delete, it works properly, but another vue script doesn't work after deletetin script with defer.. Why?

Comment: because app.js includes jquery (and vue) ?

Comment: I think yes. How to solve it?

Comment: use the jquery that is in app.js, don't load a second copy